# how i can write razor if else in razor section?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i want to write this code in section i define in

```
 if(ViewBag.Resetpass){
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=/">
}
```

in

```
@section mysection{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@section mysection {
    @if((bool)ViewBag.Resetpass)
    {
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=/" />
    }
}
```

which if you use strongly typed view models (which IMHO you should) could look like this:

```
@section mysection {
    @if(Model.Resetpass)
    {
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=/" />
    }
}
```

Comment: @jQuery On Planet MySQL, I've tested it and it rendered fine. In the layout simply include the section somewhere with `@RenderSection("mysection", false)` and in the controller action ensure you set the `ViewBag.Resetpass = true;`.